# DATA_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 5 in Chrome, how to fix?

Tags: exception, dom, google-chrome, indexeddb

Code like this:

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["main"], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
var store = transaction.objectStore("main");
var request = store.add(object);
```

It work correctly in Firefox, but in Chrome it throws "DATA_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 5" at the last line. What does this exception means? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ObjectStore has autoIncrement:true, Chrome throws this error.
[[source]](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/26/Sample-of-IndexedDB-with-Autogenerating-Keys)

Comment: Comment via [Bea](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438457/bea) - "This bug still seems to exist in the current stable version of Chrome (18.0.1025.168 as at 4-May-2012). It is fixed in the Canary build (bleeding edge, least stable). Not sure what the situation is with the Beta and Dev channels, which I am not in a position to test right now. @Alex which channel/version of Chrome is it now working in for you?"

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB [Exception 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IDBDatabaseException) means that the "Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements." This is typically because you've added a unique index, for example, while providing an object missing that attribute.

My guess would be that you're missing an indexed attribute, but to answer this question with certainty I'd need to see your `main` objectStore setup code and a JSON representation of the `object`.

Comment: It seems like it was bug in Google Chrome. Today it become work without any code change. Thanks for explanation anyway

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me on at least 2 distinct occasions: (a) when I upgraded the database version, and was writing to the older version, and (b) another case when it bizarrely got fixed by adding onerror and onsuccess handler, like so. Perhaps one of these would work for you...

```
req.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Oppsie!");
}
req.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log("Hurrah!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by many reasons. I believe it could be the bug on Linux Chrome Version 22.0.1197.0 (145517). I used the same code, Firefox worked but Chrome raised this error. I tried to clear everything. Finally I started Chrome with the command:

```
./chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome
```

and it worked.